# What if in certain algebra $w^{-n}$ is multivalued?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions

In complex numbers we have $z^{1/n}$ and $a^z$ having multiple values.

But what would happen if the inverse function $1/z$ were multi-valued?

For instance, there is such $w$ that $1/w=\pi^2/6$ but $w\ne 6/\pi^2$.

Comment: No, these are real numbers. Of course the inverse of $\pi^2/6$ is $6/\pi^2$.

Comment: If $w_1w=1$ and $ww_2=1$, $w_11=w_1$, $1w_2=w_2$ and the multiplication is associative, then $w_1=w_11=w_1(ww_2)=(w_1w)w_2=1w_2=w_2$. So, you need some of those assumptions to fail.